# Group documents by shared field while also filtering by date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a several documents that represent transactions sharing the same reference. However, they all can have different dates. They would look kinda like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('xxxxxx')
reference: ObjectId('aaaaaa1')
amount: X
createdAt:2022-05-25T21:25:08.243+00:00
```

I need to put a date limit to my aggregation, so I wrote a $match stage

```
$match: {
createdAt: {
    $gte: ISODate('2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')
```

The issue is that once I try to add the group stage and sum all of the amounts (I'll add the stage below) some may leave a document behind, if a transaction attached to the same purchase happened after the date selected but others before. I also tried using a $sort stage (createdAt: -1) to the same underwhelming result

```
$group:{
_id: '$reference',
Total: {$sum:"$amount"}
```

I guess TL;DR: is it possible to group documents starting at a specific date while ensuring every document that shares the reference field is grouped with those that share Reference, despite their time difference?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some sample data, and let us know what exactly is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$group` stage first, get `maxCreatedAt` and then filter it with `$match`.

```
{
  '$group': {
    '_id': '$reference', 
    'maxCreatedAt': {
      '$max': '$createdAt'
    }, 
    'total': {
      '$sum': '$amount'
    }
  }
}, {
  '$match': {
    'maxCreatedAt': {
      '$gte': ISODate('2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! You pointed me in the right direction. The solution was a match stage first and then grouping by $min createdAt. Worked like a charm.